# Procedure to check table for duplicates - Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Very new to SQL in general.

Have seen a few examples on how to declare table as variable in PL/SQL, however, none of them seem to do what I need.

The procedure is quite simple, check for duplicate unique numbers in a table, eg:

```
select unique_id,
       count(unique_id) as count_unique
  from table_name
having count(unique_id)>1
 group by unique_id
```

I would like to create a procedure that can be called and dynamically change `the _name` and the `unique_id`.

Something like:

```
declare 
  table_name is table:= table_1
  unique_id varchar2(100):= unique_1
begin
  select unique_id,
         count(unique_id) as count_unique
    from table_name
  having count(unique_id)>1
   group by unique_id 
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the table at runtime, you'd need dynamic SQL which means that you'd need to assemble the SQL statement you want in a string variable and execute that string.  If you have a procedure, you'd need that procedure to do something with the results of the query.  My guess is that you want to return a cursor.

Note that I'm not doing anything to validate the table and column names to avoid SQL injection attacks.  You'd probably want to use `dbms_assert` to validate the input rather than blindly trusting the caller.

```
create or replace procedure get_duplicates( p_table_name  in varchar2,
                                            p_column_name in varchar2,
                                            p_rc         out sys_refcursor )
as
  l_sql varchar2(1000);
begin
  l_sql := '  select ' || p_column_name || ', ' ||
           '         count(' || p_column_name || ') as unique_count ' ||
           '    from ' || p_table_name ||
           '   group by ' || p_column_name ||
           '  having count(' || p_column_name || ') > 1';
  dbms_output.put_line( l_sql );
  open p_rc for l_sql;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, I suppose, I'll need a dynamic SQL in order to run this check, so I can avoid running into privileges wall. Can you point me out to that?

Comment: @I.Я.Newb - Sorry, I don't follow.  Nothing about dynamic SQL has any impact on permissions.  If you have privileges to query the table, you have privileges whether you're using dynamic SQL or static SQL.  If you don't have privileges, you can't query the table.

Comment: Apologies, I might have miss-spoken - I don't have privileges for creating procedures. 
Maybe, a new question will be more appropriate for a Dynamic SQL solution of the current question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902195/dynamic-sql-for-duplicates-check-oracle-pl-sql - my question regarding Dynamic SQL with the same purpose.